# Как вытащить из строки числа и произвести их сложение

Tags: jquery, строки, split, replace

Есть textarea в которой вводятся имена людей и их возраст. Под этой textarea выводится цифра общего возраста всех людей вписанных в textarea. Как вытащить цифры возраста и сложить их, при чем обновление результата должно быть динамическим, т.е. при каждом нажатии на клавиши должно пересчитывать результат

```
$("textarea").on("keyup",  function() {

         let sum = $(this).val();

      let nums = parseInt(sum.match(/\d+/));
})
```

после этого застрял

Answer (score 1):

во первых вам лучше отслеживать не нажатие клавиш, а ввод информации в поле (тогда и Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V корректно работают и прочие способы ввода):

```
$('textarea').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    $(this).val();
});
```

еще вы бы `textarea` какой-нибудь class или id назначили бы - всё надежнее (на случай нескольких полей на странице)

Если у вас текст и числа и вам надо вычислить сумму всех чисел, то тогда можно так:

```
res = Array.from(text.matchAll("(-?\\d+)")).map(obj => parseInt(obj[0])).reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, благодаря вам разобрался)